# Why Swift Int zero is read nil in objc code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm working on a mixed objc and swift project, and I've noticed that when I have an `Int` property in a Swift class that has a value 0 when I read this value from Objc code it returns `nil`.

A Swift class with an integer property that is visible from ObjC:

```
@objc
class SwiftInt: NSObject {

    @objc let testInt: Int = 0
}
```

Now when I read this property in an Objc code, it says that `testInt` is `nil`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SwiftInt *swiftInt = [SwiftInt new];
    if (swiftInt.testInt == nil) {
        NSLog(@"This shouldn't be nil");
    }
}
```

If I set any other number than 0, that value is correctly returned, but for 0 it returns nil. The question is why is this `nil` in Objc when `Int` is a primitive type and it's a non optional? I'm using Swift 4.2.

Comment: In (Objective-)C it is possible to compare integers with pointers. `if (swiftInt.testInt == nil)` is equivalent to `if (swiftInt.testInt == 0)` – There should be a warning *"Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *')"* though

Comment: Are you interested only in `nil` or also in `NULL`, `Nil` and `NSNull`?

Comment: `ObjC` (having `C` legacy) cannot tell between `nil` and `0` at all (and `NO`/`false` too, `swiftInt.testInt == NO` or `!swiftInt.testInt` will work too).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in Objective-C `nil` defined as `__DARWIN_NULL`:

```c
#ifndef nil
# if __has_feature(cxx_nullptr)
#   define nil nullptr
# else
#   define nil __DARWIN_NULL
# endif
#endif
```

Which defined as `(void *)0` in Obj-C

So your code:

```
if (swiftInt.testInt == nil) { ... }
if (0 == nil) { ... }
if (0 == 0) { ... }
```

Which is always true

Good article about `nil` in Obj-C http://benford.me/blog/the-macro-behind-nil/